# Click Form Submit where attribute equals specific value

Tags: javascript

I would like to click Submit on this form element using JS.

`<input type="submit" value="Save Details">`

The Form does not have an ID to hook onto, the only unique value is the `value="Save Details" and there are multiple forms on the page.

I have tried the following with no luck

`document.getElementsByName('value')['Save Details].click();`

Comment: you can have unique name for each button , so when the button trigger you can check for the button name property and separate the functionality according. or using querySelector

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can't you submit form using `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();` ?

Comment: The form doesnt have an ID

Comment: @Franco :  `document.forms[0].submit();`

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelector`, but consider `type` as well because any input of type text can have similar value.

```
document.querySelector('input[type="submit"][value="Save Details"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with [css attribute equals selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```
document.querySelector('[value="Save Details"]')
```

```js
document.querySelector('[value="Save Details"]').click()
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Save Details" onclick="alert('hi')">
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** In case there is multiple element with same value, then add `input[type="submit"]` with the selector to target the input submit element.

```
document.querySelector('input[type="submit"][value="Save details"]');
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :** If you are trying to submit the form then get the form by using **[`Document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms)** and then submit by **[`submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)** method.

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Comment: Just to be on the safe side in case there's another another text input or textarea with the value `Save Details`, you can use `document.querySelector('input[type="submit"][value="Save details"]');`

Comment: @abhishek, Matter of 2 seconds.. :P

Comment: @Rayon I noticed, oh well :P